# A train travels 70 mph for x hours and then 80mph for 3$\frac3{3}{4}$ hours. If the train is coverung 405 miles of track, find the value of x.

Tags: linear-algebra

A train travels 70 mph for x hiurs and then 80mph for 3$\frac{3}{4}$ hours. If the train is coverung 405 miles of track, find the value of x.

I don't know how to answer this question. Thank you and help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, do you know how far the train went and $80$mph for $3\frac 34$ of an hour?  Do you know how to do algebra?  Like most problems this is a mater of putting this into the form $ax + b = c$ and solving.  There is *no* trick and if you know basic algebra you should know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \text{Distance} =  \text{Speed} \cdot \text{Time}$$

Since the total distance travelled must be the same on both sides, we have the equation:

$$70x + 80 \cdot 3 \frac{3}{4} = 405$$

Now solve for $x$.

Comment: O thank you I didn't realise it involved setting up an equation. X is 1.5.thank you for helping me

Comment: Next time, please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) if you haven't seen it already. You should try to put some context in your question to avoid possible downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have written mph, but as it is a train i'm thinking it's kmph and as the train is covering 405 miles in question you need to convert it into km by multiplying 1.609. So, we have the distance 405×1.609=651.645(approax.)(whereas the better approaximation is 651.784 but that doesn't matter). 
Thus the equation is (as speed×time=distance):
70x+80×15/4=651.645=> x=351.645/70.

Comment: Trains in the US use mph. In some countries the most commonly used unit for distance is miles and not kilometers.

Comment: Please also use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) as your answer is hard to read.